# React with Typescript: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I started using React with Typescript and I'm trying to add a "name" property to a "div" but Typescript is complaining about that and won't allow me to add it because that property doesn't exist.

This is the full message I get back:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; name: string; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2322)
```

How can I solve it? Here is an example of the .tsx file:

```
import React from "react";

export default function TestComponent() {
    return <div name="component-name">Test</div>;
}
```

I'm using the library react-scroll that requires a name property on the component.

Comment: Delete `name="component-name"` from the source code. ‍♂️ (This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are trying to solve a *mystery problem* by adding an illegal name attribute to the div, but we can't tell you how you should be solving that problem because you are keeping it a mystery and focusing on trying to hack a `name` attribute where it doesn't belong instead).

Comment: To copy from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes), `name` is only valid on: `<button>, <form>, <fieldset>, <iframe>, <input>, <keygen>, <object>, <output>, <select>, <textarea>, <map>, <meta>, <param>`

Comment: I'm using the library react-scroll that requires a name property on the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using the library react-scroll that requires a name property on the component.

You've misread the documentation.

Here is a quote from it:

> ```
> var Scroll   = require('react-scroll');
> var Element  = Scroll.Element;
> var scroller = Scroll.scroller;
>
> <Element name="myScrollToElement"></Element>
> ```

It requires a `name` prop on an `Element` component (which is provided by the library), **not** on a `div`.

Comment: There we go, between us we've answered the X and the Y. ;-) But yours is the more useful one. Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct, [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement) has no `name` property, and `name` is an invalid attribute for [`div` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element).

If you want to put non-standard, non-visible information on an element, use a [`data-*` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

```html
<div data-name="component-name">Test</div>
```

...and if you need to retrieve its value from the DOM element (for instance, via a ref), use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) or [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).